# Smoothness of height in Manin conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, fourier-analysis, rational-points

**Set up**: Let $K$ be a number field. Let $M_K$ be the places of $K$, and define the standard height on $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ as
$$H([x_0, \cdots, x_n]) = \prod_{v \in M_K} \max\{|x_0|_v, \cdots, |x_n|_v\}$$
[Schanuel's theorem](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1979__107__433_0.pdf) gives an asymptotic of number of points up to height $B$, as $B \to \infty$ via geometry of numbers.

Note that there is built-in non-smoothness of this height at archimedean place. The presence of $\max$ and absolute value means this is not a smooth function. Of course, one can pick other metrics so that the resulting height is smooth (perhaps up to some power). For example, using the $L^2$ norm at archimedean place we can get the height

$$H'([x_0, \cdots, x_n]) = \prod_{v | \infty} (|x_0|_v^2 + \cdots + |x_n|_v^2)^{1/2} \prod_{v < \infty} \max\{|x_0|_v, \cdots, |x_n|_v\}$$

which removes the non-smoothness from $\max$ and $|\cdot|$ (via squaring). The 1/2 power at the end makes this not smooth, but at least $H'([x_0, \cdots, x_n])^2$ is a smooth function in $x_i$'s.

**Alternative proof of Schanuel's theorem** In Section 3 of the paper of Chambert-Loir and Tschinkel, ["POINTS OF BOUNDED HEIGHT ON EQUIVARIANT COMPACTIFICATIONS OF VECTOR GROUPS"](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Etschinke/papers/yuri/00ga/ga.pdf), they give another proof of Schanuel's theorem on $\mathbb{P}^n$ via the Poisson summation formula.

It seems like the non-smoothness of standard height would forbid them to use Poisson summation, due to the Fourier transform not having good decay (so that sum of $\widehat{H}$ over additive characters do not converge). Maybe for this reason, they use smoothed version of height instead (such as the one from $L^2$ norm above), instead of the standard height.

**Question** Is the non-smoothness of standard height a hard blocker of the Fourier method? In other words,

- is there an abstraction where Poisson summation formula can still make sense and their argument can go through even for standard height?
- Or is there a way to deduce Schanuel's theorem of standard height via the version of smoothed height?

Thanks!

Comment: This is nice question. For additive groups I think that every result in the literature assumes smooth metric at the archimedean places. This is to make the application of Poisson summation easier, but I've no idea whether it is strictly necessary for the method. I think this would be a good exercise to work out for yourself in the case of projective space to see if it works with the standard height.

Comment: Incidently for toric varieties one does not need to assume that the metric is smooth in Poisson summation. This is actually the case in the original papers of Batyrev and Manin on Manin's conjecture for toric varieties, where the natural toric height on projective space is in fact the standard height.

Comment: Alternatively, there is an approach to going from smooth heights to non-smooth heights by approximating a non-smooth height by a smooth one via some form of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. I've never seen this written carefully in the literature, but it is closely related to Peyre's idea of equidistribution of rational points in the adelic points.

Comment: Feel free to email me if you would like to discuss this in more detail

Comment: sent you a follow up email, thank you!